# How to use label_replace to add a new label which value is an existing label value append a string

Tags: prometheus, promql

service_metric is
{new_service_id="pgcluster"}

We need a new label named "dbname" the value is "<new_service_id>_monitor"

label_replace(service_metric, "dbname", "$1", "new_service_id", "(.*)") is
{dbname="pgcluster", new_service_id="pgcluster"}

How to use label_replace to add a new label which value is an existing label value append a string "_monitor" please? It seems easy but tried a lot and research no result
{dbname="pgcluster_monitor", new_service_id="pgcluster"}

Answer (score 1):

Use the following PromQL:

```
label_replace(service_metric, "dbname", "${1}_monitor", "new_service_id", "(.*)")
```